# Gradle deploy artifacts to a maven repository inside a local directory

Tags: maven, gradle

What is Gradle's equivalent of Maven's:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>internal.repo</id>
        <name>Temporary Staging Repository</name>
        <url>file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
               <altDeploymentRepository>internal.repo::default::file://${project.build.directory}/mvn-repo</altDeploymentRepository>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

I have tried:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file:///tmp/mvn-repo")
        }
    }
}
```

but it throws:

```
[ant:null] Error reading settings file '/private/var/folders/KH/KH+cubLjEESWzOTqVrx-bU+++TI/-Tmp-/gradle_empty_settings7564764539012703872.xml' - ignoring. Error was: /private/var/folders/KH/KH+cubLjEESWzOTqVrx-bU+++TI/-Tmp-/gradle_empty_settings7564764539012703872.xml (No such file or directory)
```

The project that I am working on is `git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-rest.git` branch `1.0.0.RELEASE`, [project's build.gradle](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/~br=1.0.0.RELEASE/datarest/build.gradle?r=316ac5d9424435f6c09c4baa4f3109f840f93cf1).

Complete Gradle output:

```
gradle uploadArchives
The groovy configuration has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Typically, usages of 'groovy' can simply be replaced with 'compile'. In some cases, it may be necessary to additionally configure the 'groovyClasspath' property of GroovyCompile and Groovydoc tasks.
:uploadArchives
[ant:null] Error reading settings file '/private/var/folders/KH/KH+cubLjEESWzOTqVrx-bU+++TI/-Tmp-/gradle_empty_settings396071803108301794.xml' - ignoring. Error was: /private/var/folders/KH/KH+cubLjEESWzOTqVrx-bU+++TI/-Tmp-/gradle_empty_settings396071803108301794.xml (No such file or directory)
:spring-data-rest-core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-core:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-core:javadoc UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-core:javadocJar UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-core:sourcesJar UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-core:uploadArchives
:spring-data-rest-repository:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-repository:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-repository:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-repository:classes UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-repository:jar UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-repository:javadoc UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-repository:javadocJar UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-repository:sourcesJar UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-repository:uploadArchives
:spring-data-rest-webmvc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-webmvc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-webmvc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-webmvc:classes UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-webmvc:javadoc UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-webmvc:javadocJar UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-webmvc:sourcesJar UP-TO-DATE
:spring-data-rest-webmvc:uploadArchives
```

I use Gradle 1.12.

Comment: Local file URLs start with `file:///` (i.e. three slashes).

Comment: Peter, good spot, thanks, unfortunately it did not fix the issue. I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: Where's the `uploadArchives` task?

Comment: Not sure where that error comes from. Typically, publishing to a file URL works just fine.

Comment: thanks for help Peter and Opal, I have found the cause of the problem and put it in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the cause of the problem. The project I am building is a multi module project, [here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) I have found this information:

> 52.6.4.1. Multiple artifacts per project
>
> Maven can only deal with one artifact per project. This is reflected in the structure of the Maven POM. We think there are many situations where it makes sense to have more than one artifact per project. In such a case you need to generate multiple POMs. In such a case you have to explicitly declare each artifact you want to publish to a Maven repository.

So I have moved `uploadArchives` from the root level `build.gradle` to a project level `build.gradle` and this fixed the issue.

I think the error message regarding maven's setting.xml is very misleading and should be fixed by the Gradle team.

Comment: I have it in project level build.gradle.  Same error.  Not sure what is going on.  A better error would probably help a lot.

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to deploy locally (e.g. to ~/.m2) then you need:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            mavenLocal()
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried using a repository in anything other than the default but I believe you can either set the repository location in ~/.m2/settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>/tmp/mvn_repo</localRepository>
  ...
</settings>
```

or you can set the url in the gradle build file:

```
maven {
     url uri('/tmp/mvn_repo')
}
```

Comment: thanks Mikea, I have found the cause of the problem and put it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to deploy locally (e.g. to ~/.m2/repository) then:
1.mavenLocal() method in gradle checks for localRepository in settings.xml ,if it is not present

```
<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

2.add the following to build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
      repositories {
          mavenDeployer {
                         repository(url: mavenLocal().url)
                        } 
                   }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

This error also occurs when you're filtering the artifacts that you're publishing, for example, if you're using the following filter in uploadArchives to upload war files, the error will be shown for all other archives such as war and zip :

```
uploadArchives {

    repositories.mavenDeployer {            

        addFilter('war') {artifact, file ->
            artifact.ext == 'war'
        }

    }
}
```

You need to add a filter explicitly for every artifact that you need to publish :

```
        addFilter('jar') {artifact, file ->
            artifact.ext == 'jar'
        }

        addFilter('zip') {artifact, file ->
            artifact.ext == 'zip'
        }
```