# Accessing classes from non-SBT dependencies included via git in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to include a dependency from git in my SBT build. I've followed some other examples I've found on stackoverflow and got this far:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  version := "0.1.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
)

lazy val elastic = ProjectRef(uri("git://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop.git"), "elasticsearch-hadoop")

// Library dependencies
lazy val indexer = (project in file("."))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .dependsOn(elastic)
  .settings(
  projectDependencies := {
    Seq(
      (projectID in elastic).value.
        exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core").
        exclude("commons-collections", "commons-collections").
        exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging").
        exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog").
        exclude("org.apache.hadoop", "hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0").
        exclude("org.apache.spark", "spark-network-common_2.10").
        exclude("org.apache.spark", "spark-sql_2.10"))
  })
  .settings(
  libraryDependencies ++=Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.1" % "provided"
  ))
```

When running assembly I get the following error:

```
[error] /Users/nandanrao/Documents/Relink/indexer/indexer.scala:4: object elasticsearch is not a member of package org
[error] import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
```

In the other examples I found, which is the pattern I'm following, I believe the dependencies were also SBT projects. The elasticsearch-hadoop library is a java project built with gradle that has a scala project embedded within, the Spark part, and clearly the whole thing is not built with SBT.

So I'm not sure if I've even imported the project, although I might have, and I'm also not sure if those class exclusions are working. I'm hoping somebody can shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this isn't allowed: SBT can only import dependencies via Git which are themselves built with SBT. You can [publish it to your local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24011496/9204) and depend on it using `libraryDependencies` as usual. The only problem is that if you make changes in the dependency you have to republish it.